# How to detect if VBA project was sandboxed when first opened

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

## Objective: determine if project was sandboxed when opened

In MS Office when a document containing a VBA project is opened, but not trusted, users have an option to 'Enable Content'.

Opening the VBA IDE prior to enabling content confirms there is an empty 
project in the explorer (no code).

Clicking 'Enable Content' adds a second Project, this time with code. For whatever reason the 'empty' project persists. Name of Template is `NOT TRUSTED.dotm` and the name of the Document is `NOT TRUSTED.docx`.

[image: Only the highlighted project contains code]

Note: the 'empty' project is always given the default project name "TemplateProject" (whereas the actual project has whatever name was given to it using Tools > ProjectName_Properties).

**Question:**

> Is there a way to detect the presence of the empty project ***OR
>   otherwise*** determine if the project was first opened in a protected /
>   sandboxed view?

---

I'm not wedded to any particular approach, however *please assume:*

- no programmatic access to the VBA IDE
- no other projects are open

---

Edit:

I think this situation causes an "Unexpected Error" in the Rubberduck addin for VBA. Happens when opening a document but the attached template is not trusted. This is all of the code involved (in Template):

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    MsgBox "new"
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox "open"
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? With no programmatic access to the VBA IDE there's no way to determine this and I have difficulty imagining, under those circumstances, why this could be relevant.

Comment: @CindyMeister well it's an annoyance (for me at least) and I sometimes get the feeling that it adds to MS Word's confusion maintaining the document collection potentially contributing to issues when trying to find a document's template... I have no real evidence, just want to remove so it can be ruled out as a contributor.  BTW Sorry for the late reply - some lowlife broke into our house; ransacked and robbed.

Answer (score 0):

A msgbox will popup when file was opened in protected view (XL2010 up)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then MsgBox "opened in a protected / sandboxed view"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi EvR as far as I can tell this does not work... 

Can you confirm this works IF you create an XL / Word file with this macro in it AND then open the file on a PC where it (the file) is NOT trusted?  If you can confirm then can you also provide a bit more info as to how to reproduce?

Comment: It works at my end, I created an .xlsb file with the above code in the ThisWorkbook-sectiion. Then I opened this file in Protected View, after Clicking Enable Editing the msgbox appears. When normally opened, no msgbox

Comment: Ok... well I tried that (this time in excel and with xlsb) but when I click Enable Macros the workbook just opens and there are no protected view windows. If I try to run in the immediate window `?Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count` all I get is a message saying: The macros in this project are disabled....  When I enable the macros the number of ProtectedViewWindows = 0

Comment: Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count = 1 ander after running the Workbook_open event it is 0.  So running in the immediate window is after the Workbook_open event. You didn't got the messagebox?

Comment: Correct - no message for me. I have only one Workbook open. I download file from DropBox to make it not trusted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182952/discussion-between-evr-and-slowlearner).